# Why FAIL_OVERFLOW appear when Sinks emit data

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am using `Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort()` to receive data from data source. Why I chose `directBestEffort()` because I observed that `onBackpressureBuffer()` would make the memory increase.

But in my console, I saw there were some error logs when the sink emitted data. It showed `FAIL_OVERFLOW` and `FAIL_TERMINATED`. I have read the api document and it says

```
Backpressure : notify the caller with Sinks.EmitResult.FAIL_OVERFLOW if none of the subscribers can process an element. Otherwise, it ignores slow subscribers and emits the element to fast ones as a best effort. From the perspective of slow subscribers, data is dropped and never seen, but they are not terminated.
```

I can't understand what is 'none of the subscribers can process an element' means. It suddenly printed `FAIL_OVERFLOW` and printed `FAIL_TERMINATED` after `FAIL_OVERFLOW`. Like this:

```
...normal info
...normal info
2023-04-20 03:44:50.332 ERROR 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] c.g.a.service.PublisherService : onEmitFailure onNext, FAIL_OVERFLOW
2023-04-20 03:44:50.349 ERROR 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] c.g.a.service.PublisherService : onEmitFailure onNext, FAIL_TERMINATED
2023-04-20 03:44:50.349 ERROR 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] c.g.a.service.PublisherService : onEmitFailure onNext, FAIL_TERMINATED
```

I use `onErrorContinue()` operation on my flux from this sink and the flux will print error log when this operation is invoked.

My application isn't run on local and I want to reproduce this error on local but I don't know how. Is there anybody could tell me what reason may cause this error or how to reproduce this error on local.

Thank you first.